# How do I create XML file templatish way?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have to create XML files with complicated structure dynamically in .NET 4 windows service application. XML files are rather big though I have to update only small amount of tags or sections. I'd like to put XML template outside application with snippets that will insert values inside XML (like @razor engine for ASP.NET MVC Views)

```
<xml>
  <customer>@data.customer</customer>
  @foreach (var supplier in @data.suppliers) {
    <supplier>@supplier</supplier>
  }
  ...
</xml>
```

What is appropriate technology/library for that ?

Comment: Entering _"C# write file using template"_ in your favorite search engine must have pointed towards T4 templates to name something. What have you tried?

Comment: @CodeCaster, it looks like T4 feature is coupled with MSVS. I have to generate XML files without MSVS. I am not going to use preprocessed template classes also.